# grunt serve - live reload only works in app/*.html but not in app/views/*.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

i'm new to yeoman, grunt and bower.
i made an angular app with yeoman and now i try to edit the gruntfile.js. But live reload only works for files which are in 'app' - folder. in folders like 'app/views/' it doesn't live reload my page. grunt server takes notice of the change, i can see this in console output (File "app\views\partial1.html" changed.) but no live-reload happens. 
can anyone tell me how to fix that. i googled a lot but somehow i don't get this fixed.
this is my watch-part in gruntfile.js:

```
// Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            }
        },
        jsTest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
```

thx in advance for your help!!

Comment: Do you start a server with `grunt serve` or `grunt serve:dist`?

Comment: i start the server with grunt serve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all your `{,*/}` brace expansions with `**/`. So the code should look like this:

```
// Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
watch: {
    bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
    },
    js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
            livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
    },
    jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
    },
    styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
    },
    gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
            '.tmp/styles/**/*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
    }
```

For reference, `**` is a type of globbing pattern. The [Grunt documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) describes this one nicely:

> All most people need to know is that `foo/*.js` will match all files ending with .js in the foo/ subdirectory, but `foo/**/*.js` will match all files ending with .js in the foo/ subdirectory and all of its subdirectories.

Comment: OP stated that the change of that file has been detected by grunt-watch already. I doubt this will help.